# attempt to index local 'itemWidget' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Somebody can explain me this error ?? I'm new on Lua, and I wanna learn what I'm doing wrong!!

**This is my Inventory.Lua**
https://pastebin.com/KiUEajMm

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load module 'game_inventory': LUA ERROR:
/game_inventory/inventory.lua:117: attempt to index local 'itemWidget' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '__index'
    /game_inventory/inventory.lua:117: in function 'onInventoryChange'
    /game_inventory/inventory.lua:77: in function 'refresh'
    /game_inventory/inventory.lua:47: in function 'init'
    /game_inventory/inventory.otmod:8:[@onLoad]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'reloadModules'
    /client_modulemanager/modulemanager.lua:149: in function 'reloadAllModules'
    /client_modulemanager/modulemanager.otui:75: [@onClick]:2: in function </client_modulemanager/modulemanager.otui:75: [@onClick]:1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you try to access a methode of `itemWidget` while it is `nil`. So if the possibility exits that `itemWidget` can be `nil` you have to check this:

```
if itemWidget == nil then
    itemWidget:setStyle(InventorySlotStyles[slot])
    ...
end
```

Form the code you posted I can only guess why `itemWidget` is `nil`:

1. it is valid that `inventoryPanel:getChildById('slot' .. slot)` returns `nil`
2. a typo somewhere (e.g.: `'slot' .. slot` instead of `'slot ' .. slot` --> missing space)
3. wrong order: `inventoryPanel:getChildById('slot' .. slot)` only works after the init-function has ended or something similar